# Compare 2 arrays where some values are optional

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays. One array has required values and uses a ":" to identify if a value is an "elective" value. The second array displays values that a user has.

What I need to do is compare the 2 arrays and just tally how many values the user has in comparison to the number of values required - only identifying one elective per value. Below is an example:

```
$required = array( "value1:common1", "value2:common1", "value3:common2", "value4:common2", "value5", "value6", "value7" );
$have = array( "value1", "value2", "value4" )
```

The total number of required values is “5”

This is because value 1 & 2 share "common1" and value 3 & 4 share "common2".

If I were to compare the `$have` to `$required` it should display:

> 2 out of 5

I’ve looked into using the PHP code `array_intersect` and `array_diff` but they only work if the values are exactly the same.

I need to tally all `$required`, but only list 1 per common element, then I need to compare how many `$have` match but only list 1 per common element.

Comment: I've read this twice and am still confused. Can you describe the actual requirements more clearly? Maybe share your current code also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with two empty counts:

```
$required_count = 0;
$have_count = 0;
```

Now, you have two kinds of values in `$required`. Single values like `"value5"` and sets of values like `"common1"`. You can separate the set types from the single values by exploding on ':'. If it's a single value, the resulting array will have only one element, and you can update your counts according to its presence in `$have`.

```
$sets = [];
foreach ($required as $value) {
    $value = explode(':', $value);
    if (isset($value[1])) {               // member of a set of values
        $sets[$value[1]][] = $value[0];
    } else {                              // single value
        $required_count++;
        $have_count += in_array($value[0], $have);
    }
}
```

After you've extracted the sets of values from the `$required` array, you can check each of them against `$have` using `array_intersect`.

```
foreach ($sets as $set) {
    $required_count++;
    $have_count += array_intersect($have, $set) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly! Thank you!